# How to invert $f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{3}x}{\sqrt{1+3x^2}}$

Tags: functions

Consider the function 
$f:(-1,1)\to(-1,1)$,
$f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{3}x}{\sqrt{1+3x^2}}$

To find $f^{-1}$ we have to show that f is injective and surjective.

Let $a,b\in(-1,1)$.

Then $f(a)=f(b)$ is equivalent to $\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{\sqrt{1+3a^2}}$=$\frac{\sqrt{3}b}{\sqrt{1+3b^2}}$.

It implies $(a-b)(a+b)=0$, which is problematic with $a=-b$.

To show surjectivity we have to show that for every $y$ there is an $x$ such that $f(x)=y,$ with which I'm also stuck!

Comment: About injective if $a$ and $b$ have different signs then the expressions $\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{\sqrt{1+3a^2}},\frac{\sqrt{3}b}{\sqrt{1+3b^2}}$ also have different signs

Comment: You could also show that there is an inverse. Then you get surjectivity (right inverse) and injectivity (left inverse) for free.

Comment: $y=\frac{\sqrt3 \space x}{\sqrt{1+3x^2}}\iff x=\frac{y}{\sqrt{3-3y^2}}$

Answer (score 2):

Try first solving
$$
y=\frac{\sqrt{3}\,x}{\sqrt{1+3x^2}}
$$
First let's try it for $y>0$, so also $x>0$ (if it exists). Then we get
$$
y^2=\frac{3x^2}{1+3x^2}=1-\frac{1}{1+3x^2}
$$
that is
$$
\frac{1}{1+3x^2}=1-y^2
$$
This is possible only if $0<y<1$ and, in this case, we have
$$
1+3x^2=\frac{1}{1-y^2}
$$
so
$$
3x^2=\frac{1}{1-y^2}-1=\frac{y^2}{1-y^2}
$$
and so
$$
x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}
$$
If $y\le0$ you find exactly the same formula under the condition $-1<y\le0$.

So $f$ is indeed invertible (over the range $(-1,1)$).

Note that this *does* show injectivity. However, if you're requested to go the hard way, here it is.

Suppose
$$
\frac{\sqrt{3}\,a}{\sqrt{1+3a^2}}
=
\frac{\sqrt{3}\,b}{\sqrt{1+3b^2}}
$$
Then either $a\ge 0$ and $b\ge0$ or $a<0$ and $b<0$.

Let's do the first case. Squaring we get
$$
\frac{3a^2}{1+3a^2}=\frac{3b^2}{1+3b^2}
$$
or
$$
1-\frac{1}{1+3a^2}=1-\frac{1}{1+3b^2}
$$
that implies
$$
1+3a^2=1+3b^2
$$
and therefore
$$
a^2=b^2
$$
so $a=b$.

Similarly for the case $a<0$ and $b<0$.

Comment: Thank you ! So to show that f is injective we have work on two cases like what you did here ?

Comment: @user233658 We have *already* proved $f$ is injective!

Comment: We have to show that f(a)=f(b)=> a=b to show thar a function is injective ?

Comment: @user233658 We showed it has an inverse!

Comment: But in the exercise it asked us to show that its injective and surjective then cunclude its inverse !

Comment: @user233658 Probably they're asking for the range as the function is not surjective over the reals. But there's not a unique way for answering a question. I added the solution for injectivity. The range is computed as I showed before.

Comment: @user233658 As you can clearly see, it's not much different from finding the inverse, is it?